# How do I change div size when screen size changed?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, responsive-design

When I change the screen size, I want to change the div size according (note: without using a button or component)

```
    <div id="main-page">
      <div class="container-fluid p-0">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="height" style="color: wheat;"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
    var width = $(this).width();
    var height = $(this).height();
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#main-page").width(width).height(height);
    }) ;
```

Comment: Don't use javascript, use css - eg `#height { height: 100vh }` See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units for more

Comment: I would also go with a css solution although probably use 100% height instead of vh: https://jsfiddle.net/6o4gtp97/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to need to set the width and height to desired element on [`resize event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event). The [`resize event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) fires when the document view (window) has been resized. See the following example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  changeSize();
});


$(window).on("resize", function() {
  changeSize();
});

function changeSize() {
  var width = $(this).width();
  var height = $(this).height();
  $("#main-page").width(width).height(height);
  $("#height").text(`Height: ${$("#main-page").height()} Width: ${$("#main-page").width()}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-page">
  <div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div id="height" style="color: wheat;">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```